# PHP Notice – yii\base\ErrorException

Tags: php, oop, yii, yii2, yii-extensions

Use of undefined constant INTL_ICU_VERSION - assumed 'INTL_ICU_VERSION

**Yii Framework/2.0.7**

> $checks[] = array(
>                   'title' => Yii::t('base', $title),
>                   'state' => 'ERROR',
>                   'hint' => 'Install INTL Extension'
>               );
>           }
>
> ```
>     $icuVersion = (defined('INTL_ICU_VERSION')) ? INTL_ICU_VERSION : 0;
>     $icuMinVersion = '4.8.1';
>     $title = 'PHP - INTL Extension - ICU Version (' . INTL_ICU_VERSION . ')';
>     if (version_compare($icuVersion, $icuMinVersion, '>=')) {
>         $checks[] = array(
>             'title' => Yii::t('base', $title),
>             'state' => 'OK'
>         );
>     } else {
>         $checks[] = array(
>             'title' => Yii::t('base', $title),
>             'state' => 'WARNING'
>
>
>           'hint' => 'Install INTL Extension'
>         );
>     }
>
>     $icuVersion = (defined('INTL_ICU_VERSION')) ? INTL_ICU_VERSION : 0;
>     $icuMinVersion = '4.8.1';
>     $title = 'PHP - INTL Extension - ICU Version (' . INTL_ICU_VERSION . ')';
>     if (version_compare($icuVersion, $icuMinVersion, '>=')) {
>         $checks[] = array(
>             'title' => Yii::t('base', $title),
>             'state' => 'OK'
>         );
>     } else {
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's [solution](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/69245-error-installing-yii2-on-local-computer/) of your problem I guess:

Or maybe try to update Php version